# React Firebase - Uncaught exception signInWithEmailAndPassword, email must be a valid string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux

Greetings fellow developers. I'm learning React, without much knowledge of JS (Yes, I know it is a silly decision), for the purpose of getting on idea what React is.

I've started following this guy's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9iWstfXntcj8f-dFZ4UtlN3) on building things. I have found several cases where the tutorial is outdated, but I've managed to correct these.

Now I have stumbled upon an issue that many people have encountered, but the solutions to it were very specific to the code people have written. I've looked through many SO posts, also had a look in Firebase docs, as well as asking dev colleagues for help.

The issue is when I enter **correct** credentials for login and press the button, I get an error:

> "Uncaught exception:Error signInWithEmailAndPassword failed: First argument “email” must be a valid string".

I have tried different ways to combat this e.g. returning new promise and as shown below, returning async function.

**authAction.js**

```
export const logIn = (credentials) => {
console.log("Login attempt, login authActions");
return async (dispatch, getState) => {
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(
        credentials.email,
        credentials.password
    ).then(() => {
        console.log("Login Successful")
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_SUCCESS'})
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        dispatch({ type: 'LOGIN_ERROR', err})
    })
};
```

**LogIn.js**

```
class LogIn extends Component {
state = {
    email: '',
    password: ''
}

handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
        [e.target.id] : [e.target.value]
    })
}

handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.logIn(this.state);
}
render() {
    const { authError, auth } = this.props;

    if(auth.uid) return <Redirect to='/'/>

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <form className="white" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <h5 className="grey-text text-darker-3">Login</h5>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" id="password" onChange={this.handleChange}/>
                </div>
                <div className="input-field">
                    <button className="btn pink lighten-1 z-depth-0">Login</button>
                    <div className="red-text center">
                    { authError ? (<p>{ authError }</p>) : (null) }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
console.log("Loggin attempt, stateToProps");
return{
    authError: state.auth.authError,
    auth: state.firebase.auth
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
return {
    logIn: (credentials) => dispatch(logIn(credentials))
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(LogIn)
```

**authReducer**

```
const initState = {
authError: null

const authReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
switch(action.type) {
    case 'LOGIN_ERROR' :
        console.log("LOGIN ERROR .....");
        return {
            ...state,
            authError: 'Login failed'
        }
    case 'LOGIN_SUCCESS' :
        console.log(' login successful');
        return {
            ...state,
            authError : null
        }
    case 'LOGOUT_SUCCESS' :
        console.log("logout completed");
        return {
            state
        }
    default :
        return state;
}
export default authReducer
```

**index.js**

```
const store = createStore(
rootReducer,
compose(applyMiddleware(thunk.withExtraArgument({getFirebase, getFirestore})),
reduxFirestore(firebase, fbConfig)
)
);

const rrfProps = {
    firebase,
    config: fbConfig,
    dispatch: store.dispatch,
    createFirestoreInstance
  };
```

I have uploaded code that is (I think) relevant to the issue. Also please excuse the missing braces, I found it challenging to connect multiple lines of code including empty lines.

Thanks for the support beforehand!

Comment: The first thing you can try is right before calling the sign in function, `console.log(credentials.email)` and see if it's correct.

Comment: This is a good question. No obvious errors jump out at me. As technophyle states, it's nice to log what is actually sent to the external api just before the request itself. If that turns out to be undefined, i'd then start checking where i lose the credentials. Is the state updated properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in this code:

```
``handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
   [e.target.id] : [e.target.value]
   })
}``
```

Change this to:

```
``handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({
    [e.target.id] : e.target.value
  })
}``
```

You made an array of the values of your password and email credentials